# Is there an asus webstorage client?

Tags: 10.04

Is there '[Asus webstorage client](https://www.asuswebstorage.com/navigate/features/)' for Ubuntu 10.04? I don't want to use wine.

I have an Asus and when I bought it I was given one year free 500 gb backup. It works in windows but can i make it work in ubuntu?

from [here](http://www.asuswebstorage.com/navigate/downloads/).

"»If you are using non-Eee PC preloaded Linux or other operating systems:
We are porting ASUS WebStorage software to support all major operating systems. We will send you an email to notify the release. Please stay tuned."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be one on the main downloads page.

http://www.asuswebstorage.com/navigate/downloads/

Comment: Just took a peek at it. While I'm not on my Ubuntu computer right now, it appears that it's only if your Asus had Ubuntu pre-installed by them - not if you installed it yourself.

Comment: I have it installed on the windows partition. And I don't like windows that much.